# How to code using python so it can tell me the mode without using input or print and using def, if and ele

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mean, median

My code so far, but I get an error testing it:

```
# without using any collection data types like list or set, this
# function determines which value appears the most often and returns it.

def mode3(a, b, c):

    # starting value for variable ans. Replace it with the
    # actual answer before reaching the return stmt.if int(value) < 0 :


    ans = None
if int(mode3(a, a, b)):
    ans = "a"
if int(mode3(a, b, b)):
    ans = "b"
if int(mode3(a, c, c)):
    ans = "c"
else:
    return ans
```

[Original screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti68K.png)

Comment: You should type your code here instead of pasting a linked image of code, to get useful help.

Comment: I strongly urge you to edit your question before you get drastially downvoted for poor quality

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is

```
def mode3(a, b, c):
    if a == b or a == c:
        return a
    elif b == c:
        return b
    else:
        return None
```

and you can test it like

```
mode3(1, 1, 1)     # => 1
mode3(1, 1, 2)     # => 1
mode3(1, 2, 1)     # => 1
mode3(2, 1, 1)     # => 1
mode3(1, 2, 3)     # => None
```